# Have to click submit twice to get form to submit when I implemented reCaptcha v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, recaptcha

I've just implemented reCaptcha v3 on a form (the contact form of my website which was using reCaptcha v2 got hacked, so I have setup a test form to get the implementation right before I roll out).

Here's the script that is handling all the reCaptcha stuff:

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function(event){ 
  event.preventDefault();
                
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('[My_Site_Key]', {action: 'contactForm'}).then(function(token) {
        $('#contactForm').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="g-recaptcha-response" value="' + token + '">');
        console.log(token)
        $('#contactForm').unbind('submit').submit();
    });
  });
});
```

Obviously, [My_Site_Key] has the real site in it, I've just removed it here.

When I click SUBMIT on the form, I see the token logged to the console, but to get the form to actually submit (and trigger the action), I need to click the submit button a second time. When I do click a second time, the form action is triggered and I get the test email that the server-side script generates upon getting a successful reCaptcha response.

I thought that the whole point of the .unbind('submit').submit() was that it removed the event handler binding (and thus, effectively reverses the effect of the event.preventDefault() ) and then submitted the form, but it doesn't seem to be doing so.

Anyone got any suggestions how this can be edited so that I don't need to click the submit button twice to get the form to actually submit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you have the submit button named "submit", it causes the submit button to need to be clicked twice to make this work.
After talking to a friend who had the same issue, I've renamed the submit button to be name="submit2" and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

An [HTMLFormElement](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element) has a property for every named element (be it a button or an input field) inside it. If you name such an element `submit`, this element overwrites the `HTMLFormElement::submit()` function so that you can no longer programmatically submit the form.

You can still submit it interactively by pressing the submit button, however.